# Avoid "Error 1004: no cells were found" when counting a blank column

Tags: excel, vba

I am building a macro which includes an intermediate step for counting the results of a search.

If the search does not come up with results, the column stays blank and that causes the count to give a 1004-error.

My code looks like this:

```
Sub Test()
Dim z As Integer
z=Worksheets("Pumps").Range("N:N").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
Range("O1").Value = z
End Sub
```

Does anybody have an idea how to control this ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can use : `On Error Resume Next` and `On Error GoTo 0`

Answer (score 2):

Use error handling with `SpecialCells`.

Plus I have removed the unnecessary use of a count.

```
Dim rng1 As Range
On Error Resume Next
Set rng1 = Worksheets("Pumps").Range("N:N").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
On Error GoTo 0
If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then Range("O1").Value = rng1.Cells.Count
```

Answer (score 0):

You could solve it like this

```
Sub Test()

Dim z As Integer

If Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(Range("N:N")) >= "1" Then
    z = Worksheets("Pumps").Range("N:N").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
    Range("O1").Value = z
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The range returned by `SpecialCells()` can be empty, so test it beforehand:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim results As Range

    Set results = Worksheets("Pumps").Range("N:N").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    If results Is Nothing Then
        Range("O1") = 0
    Else
        Range("O1") = results.Count
    End If
End Sub
```

BTW, maybe you should qualify `Range("O1")` to get the return value onto the sheet you intend, like in `Worksheets("Pumps").Range("O1")`.